# modifier consumes all gas

Tags: solidity, gas, modifiers

Given a modifier:

```
modifier yetNotCalculated() {
    require(calculated == false);
    _;
}
```

and then using it in my function:

```
function calculateResult() public yetNotCalculated {
    calculate();
    calculated = true;
}
```

When the modifier rejects further processing (`calculated` is set to `true`), it consumes all my gas :( ! is this a desired behaviour ?

Here I am invoking that function using web3 library, and that what I get as receipt:

```
    { blockHash: '0xc8219ac506e4020f61e199126d8b578c8d8219222286d684661415593c251495',
  blockNumber: 12476,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 2100000,
  from: '0xe6cb4d38ae1f3458f5095652a68b304b3aa7f82c',
  gasUsed: 2100000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  root: '0x6047a5fe941496e089cf73e0c2cbd7db1608794bac0a73368fcfcd34833a1aef',
  to: '0xf8b8741024621ee0936bafac55ff544421d7924b',
  transactionHash: '0xf8b40eeb956b425fc4cfadec1c1cc2a479addbc635c74fb6000945fedd41696a',
  transactionIndex: 0 }
```

as you can see 2100000 gas was used which is my gas limit.
why is that :) ?
Thanks

Comment: Gas should be returned with `require(false);`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085107/2318492

Comment: What solidity version are you using in your contract? The revert() opcode is different pre-byzantium.

Comment: I am using geth 1.7.3 on my local private test network.

solc --version                                                                                       
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.Linux.g++
@Valdi_K

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `modifier`, it's the `require`. `require` reverts/errors if the condition is false, so, if `calculated==true` then revert.

This might not be a great application for `modifier` or `require`. Have you considered `if(!calculated) calculate(); return true;`?

Hope it helps

Comment: what I would like to achieve is when a certain condition is not true, and that condition can be checked right at the very begining, there should be no gas consumed. I am not sure if it's possible that the user's transactions took 0 gas when function was rejected on modifier, but that would be great if possible....

Comment: Separate concerns. You can make `calculated` `public` so anyone can see ahead of time if it's already done. Then decide if you want to `return true`, `false` or `revert()` in the case they ask for it again. I might incline to "ask a silly question, lose all your gas" given that you provided a "free" getter they could check first if they weren't so lazy. It is not possible to return a `false` for free. Although the cost to check and `return` would be tiny, the user will pay for the computation to run the logic.

Answer (score 0):

“If you're asking about gas consumption up until the require statement, then the answer is yes. As of the Byzantium release, all gas consumed up to the point of a require statement is consumed, but any remaining gas is returned. Prior to Byzantium, require() and assert() were identical and all gas would be consumed.
From the Solidity docs:
Internally, Solidity performs a revert operation (instruction 0xfd) for a require-style exception and executes an invalid operation (instruction 0xfe) to throw an assert-style exception. In both cases, this causes the EVM to revert all changes made to the state...Note that assert-style exceptions consume all gas available to the call, while require-style exceptions will not consume any gas starting from the Metropolis release.” (By Adam Kipnis)

As far as I know this is the right answer.